# batch file: echo '|' character

Tags: batch-file

How can I do:

```
echo [-help | -h]: displays help
```

At the moment when I do it I get:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

This works but

```
echo "[-help | -h]: displays help"
```

it also prints the quotes, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
echo [-help ^| -h]: displays help
```

The `^` escapes the pipe.

Comment: On a side note, the `^` escape can also be used to escape `<` and `>` and `^` itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways:

1. Escaping with carets
   You can escape any character (but not the percent) with a caret

   Echo [-help ^¦ -?]
2. Using delayed expansion
   As the content of a delayed expansion isn't parsed any more, it can contain all characters.

   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "helpStr=[ -help | -?]"
   echo !helpStr!
3. Disappearing quotes
   Quotes can also escape special characters, but they be echoed also.
   Disappearing quotes works like normal quotes, but they will be replaced with nothing before echoing.

   3.1 With delayed expansion, you add !"=! anywhere you need a quote, this expression will be replaced with nothing, later

   `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`
   `echo !"=![ -help | -?]`

   3.2 Without delayed expansion you could use a FOR-loop

```
FOR %%^" in ("") do (
    echo %%~"[ -help | -?]`
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The escape character in DOS  is (usually)  ^

So try:

```
echo [-help ^| -h]: displays help
```

It's a bit weird though and lots of exceptions. See here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: [there's no escape character in DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Windows_Command_Prompt), only in Windows CMD. [They're completely different things](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 0):

The `[-help | -h]` means either `-help` or `-h`. Try running the command again, with `-h` as the only argument.

Comment: I want to print text, i dont want to run it

Comment: Aha. Can't you escape the whole line in quotes?

Comment: That would also output the quotes in DOS. Silly DOS.